# GPUImage - low FPS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, gpuimage

I am currently using **GPU framework** to record a video along with **WhiteBalance and Exposure Filters** but the FPS is very poor (About 12 FPS). I have used the above filters in GPUImage original demo Code (**SimpleVideoFilter**) but the results are same.

Here is the Method that I am using to record a video with combined filters. These are the results for iPhone 5, iPod Touch which has max 30 FPS support.

Any Ideas to achieve **FPS upto 28** or something with the **AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh** and WhiteBalance,Exposure filter together!! Thanks !!

```
-(void)recordVideo{

    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
    videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;

    filter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];
    [videoCamera addTarget:filter];

    GPUImageFilterGroup *group = (GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter;
    GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter *whiteBalance = [[GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter alloc] init];
    [group addFilter:whiteBalance];

    GPUImageExposureFilter *exposureFilter = [[GPUImageExposureFilter alloc] init];
    [group addFilter:exposureFilter];
    [whiteBalance addTarget:exposureFilter];

    [group setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:whiteBalance]];
    [group setTerminalFilter:exposureFilter];

    filter = group;
    [videoCamera addTarget:filter];

    GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
    NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
    unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];
    movieWriter.encodingLiveVideo = YES;
    movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(1080.0, 1920.0)];
    [filter addTarget:movieWriter];
    [filter addTarget:filterView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];

    double delayToStartRecording = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t startTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayToStartRecording * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Start recording");

        videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
        [movieWriter startRecording];

        double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
        dispatch_time_t stopTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(stopTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
            videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
            [movieWriter finishRecording];
            NSLog(@"Movie completed");
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: What's the framerate without these two filters? Recording 1080p video can be intensive. If you just use a single GPUImageBrightnessFilter, for example, what framerate do you see? Also, make sure this is under bright lighting conditions, as the framerate of the camera itself will drop in order to increase exposure in indoors conditions.

Comment: The framerate without these filters is 25. Also using a single GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter I get 15. The results are in Room under normal working tube light. But under same condition as your sample code has used sepia filter it gives 25 FPS. Why too much of difference is caused to even with single Filter ?